# Buying add on from PSN for a disc game

Tags: ps4

I have Just Dance 2019 for PS4 on disc, then I bought 12 months pass for the unlimited account from PSN, but I can't find the add-on anywhere, also the game still ask me to subscribe. can anyone help?
Where can I find it? How to install it?
How to ask for a refund if I didn't find it?

Comment: If you go to the PSN store and go to the addon page again, does it say Purchase or Download?

Comment: I can't find it in there. I looked for it everywhere.

Comment: I can see it in transactions that it is purchased

Comment: You may have to contact the game's support line then.

Comment: Dwfinitly contact the support (game/psn). It works just fine to buy a DLC for a disc game from PSN (done so with Monster Hunter World (Iceborne))